# Intuition behind multiplication

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, intuition

I recently [read this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31725/intuition-behind-matrix-multiplication) and the highest voted comment and it got me thinking. How does think about multiplication if it is decimals?

For example, if we have $3.9876542 \times 2.3156479$ then how would we multiply that? It doesn't make a lot of sense to add $3.9876542$, $2.3156479$ times. Then how would you think about multiplying that i.e. what's the intuition of behind that?

Thanks!

Comment: You can write $5\cdot3$ or $5\times3$.  There's no need for $5*3$.  That is a device introduced for use when you're restricted to the characters on the keyboard and must use the letter x for something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A rectangle with sides $3.9876542\,\mathrm m$ and $2.3156479\,\mathrm m$ can be viewed as $3987654200$ by $2315647900$ namometers instead. Then you can actually count all thos tiny square-nanometers (or simplify this by repaeted addition!) and obtain an area of $9234003074156180000\,\mathrm{nm}^2$. Since there are $1000000000000000000\,\mathrm{nm}^2$ in each $\mathrm  m^2$, you end up with $9.23400307415618\,\mathrm m^2$ and thus we should have $3.9876542\cdot 2.3156479 =  9.23400307415618$.

Answer (score 7):

It's the area of a rectangle with side lengths $3.9876542$ and $2.3156479$.

Answer (score 5):

The term "decimal" is an abbreviation for *decimal fraction.*

And  $3.9876542$ is a convenient *abbreviation* for $\dfrac{39876542}{10000000}$.

It is not difficult to give meaning to $\dfrac{a}{b} \cdot \frac{c}{d}$, where $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers. Area is a good choice. So is distance travelled if speed is $\frac{a}{b}$ and time is $\frac{c}{d}$.

Answer (score 1):

Just think in terms of fractions.  With fractions, multiplication can be interpreted as meaning "of", like usual.  For example, $\frac23 \times \frac57$ is $\frac23$ *of* $\frac57$ -- and if you didn't know how to multiply fractions, you could draw a picture or slice up a cake to figure out the answer.