# Why multiply the rows of the first matrix by the columns of the second matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I want to dig deep in linear algebra and I'm looking for an explanation on why we multiply rows by columns to achieve a transformation where did that approach came from ? [Matrix multiplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioHFJ.png)

Comment: This is to be consistent with the composition of linear transformations.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31725/intuition-behind-matrix-multiplication) post has plenty of in-depth answers.

Comment: This video is very good at explaining the concept https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkY2DOUCWMU. It might be useful to watch the whole series if you're not so sure on the intuition behind linear algebra